# django cookiecutter shared database server

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

This is a very easy question, but for some reason I can’t find the answer myself. I have two microservices in Django, I combined them in Docker, but for some reason they don’t want to connect to the postgres database. So how can i resolve this. Here is my configs (im using django-cookiecutter), dockerfiles is stay standart
Service A:
`.envs/.local/.postgres`

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGRES_HOST = postgres
POSTGRES_PORT = 5432
POSTGRES_DB = service_A
POSTGRES_USER = debug
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = debug
```

service B:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGRES_HOST = postgres
POSTGRES_PORT = 5432
POSTGRES_DB = service_B
POSTGRES_USER = debug
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = debug
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
  postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  service_A:
    build:
      context: service_A
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: service_A_local
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'
    command: /start

  service_B:
    build:
      context: service_B
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: service_B_local
    ports:
      - '8002:8002'
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./service_A/compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - service_A/.envs/.local/.postgres
      - service_B/.envs/.local/.postgres
```

Comment: When the `postgres` container starts, what value do you expect the environment variable `POSTGRES_DB` to have?  A common microservice practice is to have a separate isolated database per container, and this is fairly easy to set up in Docker; does doing this help resolve this issue?

Comment: thanks for this information. This helped a lot